# image for button in android studio

Tags: android, kotlin

This is my button class implementation:

```
package com.example.myproject

import android.R
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Color
import android.os.CountDownTimer
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.ImageView
import kotlin.properties.Delegates


data class MyButton() : androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton(context) {

    init {
        this.text = "test"

        this.setOnClickListener { v ->
            Log.d("CLICK", "click")
        }

        object: CountDownTimer(_time, 1000) {
            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                var rnd = (0..20).random()
                if (rnd < 10) {
                    this.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.notebook)  //notebook
                } else {
                    this.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.desktop_pc)  //desktop PC
                }
            }

            override fun onFinish() {
                exitProcess(-1)
            }
        }.start()
    }
}
```

So I want to, based on some random generator, put whether notebook image or desktop PC image on my button. This is my res folder:

res > drawable > notebook.png, desktop_pc.png

Both images I put there using copy-paste. But the problem is that the method R.drawable cannot find these two files, it's not possible to load them from this folder. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think your R import is wrong, you are using android.R but should be your 'application package.R' Just change it